# What did James and Lily Potter do for a living?

Tags: harry-potter

What did James and Lily Potter do for a living? Did they have any job?

Comment: FYI, it's not necessary (and [not encouraged](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/is-it-encouraged-to-delete-your-own-questions-if-they-have-possible-duplicates)) to delete your question just because it's been closed as a duplicate. Duplicates of good questions are still good questions, and they improve searchability.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks! I deleted because I found my answer. undeleted now that you said it might be helpful.

Comment: And upvoted. Welcome to SFF, by the way :-)

Comment: This doesn't look duplicate to me. The other question talks about wealth and this one talks about job. Not all wealthy people are lazy-** to not go for job.

Comment: @BabyYoda /Sachin except this question is specifically answered by ykombinator's answer. Reading past the accepted answer can sometimes be helpful! Also the OP stated themselves that their question was answered.